# Using AWS's ECR get-login-password and --password-stdin with Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, powershell, amazon-ecs

The [recommended way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html) to authenticate docker with AWS ECR in order to push/pull images is using the following command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | 
docker login --username AWS --password-stdin AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with powershell, resulting with the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ 
failed with status: 400 Bad Request
```

It works fine with CMD, but not Powershell.  After searching around for solution, I found that the issue is that the first section of the script that gets the password, appends a new line to it, which causes the second part of the script to fail.  I searched for a way to strip that new line from the first section with no success.  This does not work:

```
echo $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1) |
 docker login --username AWS --password-stdin AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The only way I can get it working is by splitting the script into two commands, like this:

```
$password = aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1
docker login --username AWS --password $password AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The problem is that this approach results in the following warning:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
```

Any ideas/workarounds?  Thanks.

EDIT:
Link to github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/270

Comment: a lot of things don work in powershell/cmd. What are you trying to automate on windows machine?

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm trying to automate pulling docker images from AWS Elastic Image Registry to a windows machine running Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Hit this problem from a Jenkins pipeline that uses powershell scripts to push images to AWS ECR. I agree it is related to the newline. Using .Trim() or -replace '\r?\n\z' all seemed to have no effect on what was passed after the pipe into --password-stdin.

I still wanted the upload output to appear in the Jenkins logs so I have switched to using the following workaround for the moment.

```
docker login --username AWS --password (Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password https://AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

It still gives the warning about using --password but keeps it in PowerShell.

Comment: I created an issue with AWS here, if you want to keep track if it will ever get fixed, though given the root cause I find it unlikely: https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/270

Answer (score 1):

After wasting hours on this, I've finally found a solution.  As I mentioned earlier, this works fine in CMD, so I figured I'd try to run CMD from PowerShell.  Turns out you can do it like this:
`cmd.exe \c "your command"`

I then tried this, and it worked:

```
cmd.exe \c "aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```